# how to add boxblur to rtmp stream with ffmpeg

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

On my nginx server,i am looking for a solution add a blurring to a stream rtmp to rtmp, I have found only a solution for mp4, can we adapt this to an rtmp?
my stream code:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://192.168.1.116/camera/output -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/stream
```

Code that works in mp4:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=318:40:322:312,boxblur=2[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=322:312[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0-map -0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

I voluntarily deactivate the sounds

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://192.168.1.116/camera/output -vf boxblur=2 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/stream
```

Note that filtering the video requires it to be re-encoded, so `-c copy` was changed to `-c:v libx264 -c:a copy`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help,
yes thank you, I understand, I tested, -vf it didn't work, so I replaced it with -filter complex, the problem is that the blurring is applied on the whole screen and not just on the part I wanted :
1920x1080 screen, blurring at the bottom right, dimension 940x100:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://192.168.1.116/camera/input -filter_complex "[0:v]boxblur=2[bg];[0:v]crop=940:100:976:976[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=976:976" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/stream
```

And do you think it's normal that it needs more than 90% of CPU? for adding the blurring